# AppleScript get text from a google translate website without opening safari

Tags: web, applescript, gettext

Is there a way to search text from a page without opening a safari tab?

What I'm trying to do is for example

https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/ &TEXT

Open this URL in background and get the result & set it as a variable

Comment: You can try `do shell script` and invoke `curl`, but it looks like you'll have to play with the user-agent string (`--user-agent`) to get it to work (possibly), because something like `curl 'https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/hello'` yields response `Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/</code> from this server
https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/hello`.

Comment: Use `cURL` and parse the html text.

Comment: Thank you, I'll gonna try that

Comment: To potentially save you some time: `curl -L --user-agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/602.4.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0.3 Safari/602.4.8' 'https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/hello'`, which emulates Safari, does yield a result, but _not the translation_. A factor may be that Google may not want their service accessed this way (I'm only guessing).

Comment: I am also guessing that google has rigged the sight to avoid using it as a SOAP service.